# Change limits of a time signal at matlab

Tags: matlab, signals

i am a beginner an have an easy question. I have a signal on y-axis and time signal on x-axis. I need to change boundaries of the time signal. It's between 0 and 18 seconds, but i want to change in between 5 and 10. I used already "xlim", it work for plot but actually i want to create a new time signal.

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: There are many ways to cut (or change speed of, or ...) a 18s signal to make a 5s signal. So you should be more precise in your question. Also please add the code that you used to plot with "xlim", that will help people understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't post your code I'll need to make some assumptions. I'll assume you have your data stored in row vectors `x` and `y` and that `x` is uniform and monotonically increasing.

**1.** Construct a truncated signal using [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1).

```
index = x >= 5 & x <= 10;
x_new = x(index);
y_new = y(index);

plot(x_new, y_new);
```

The above only takes a subset of the data, if `x` doesn't contain 5 and 10 then the plot will be truncated. If you're dealing with time series data *this is probably the most reasonable approach since it doesn't change the sampling rate*.

**2.** Re-sampling the signal between 5 and 10 using [interpolation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).

```
num_samples = 100;
x_new = linspace(5, 10, num_samples);
y_new = interp1(x, y, x_new);

plot(x_new, y_new);
```

This may not exactly match the original plot since the original samples aren't guaranteed to be included. However it will exactly span the desired domain.

**3.** If you don't care that `x` is uniform but want to create a plot that exactly matches the original then you can append the bounds of `x` to the subset from method 1 and use interp1 to sample `y`.

```
x_min = 5;    x_max = 10;
index = x > x_min & x < x_max;
x_new = [x_min, x(index), x_max];
y_new = interp1(x, y, x_new);

plot(x_new, y_new);
```

**Example**

Example demonstrating the differences between the different methods, plotted with additional offset and markings at samples for clarity.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. It works very well!

Comment: But now how can i specify my y values to x_new? Because surely i got an error "Vectors must be the same lengths". If you know that, would be great. Thnak you!

Comment: @A.U Sorry I don't know what you mean. `y_new` contains the values corresponding to `x_new` in all the examples I gave. If you have another question please post it as a new question. Also, if you take the time to construct a [mcve] you're much more likely to get quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the elements `n` from the back of a vector `y` and store the result in `y_cut`, you should be able to do that with:

```
y_cut = y(1:end-n);
```

It would be important to know in which form you stored the time signal.
If you have one value for each second the solution would be:

```
y_cut = y(5:10);
```

But I assume you're storing your y-values as samples with a given sample rate `fs`
One second would then be equal to fs (for example 44100 for a CD audio file, resulting in 44100 samples per second) and the solution would be:

```
y_cut = y(5*fs:10*fs);
```

I hope I could help.

Cheers,
Simon